# How to save data into next columns

Tags: python, csv, python-3.6, file-writing

I am writing a csv file which appends data into rows like this
[image]

but want it like this
[image]

I have list [] where i am appending the data and using it to to write file :

```
def writefiles(alldata, filename):
    with open ("./"+ filename, "w") as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        csvfile.writerow("")
        for i in range(0, len(alldata)):
            csvfile.writerow(alldata[i])

writefiles(alldata, "Data.csv")
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your `alldata` into the desired format with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter
writefiles([[k, *chain.from_iterable(r for _, *r in g)] for k, g in groupby(alldata, key=itemgetter(0))], "Data.csv")
```

Comment: I've updated my answer so that you can simply replace your call of `writefiles(alldata, "Data.csv")` with my code.